# How do you extend the Java Exception class with a custom exception that takes a String parameter?

Tags: java, exception

So I see you can extend the Exception class like so:

```
public FooException(Exception e)
{
    this.initCause(e);
}
```

But what if you want to pass not an exception to FooException's constructor - but a String:

```
public FooException(String message)
{
    // what do i do here?
}
```

What would the body of the Constructor look like in that case?

Comment: I don't think what you're doing in that first code snippet is an example of extending another type... can you expand on that code snippet some?

Answer (score 3):

`Exception` also has a [`String` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String%29).

```
class FooException extends Exception {
    public FooException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm ... that's not how you extend an exception. Create your own subclass which already takes a string as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

To extend a class you should do something like this:

```
public class FooException extends Exception {
    FooException(String message) {
         super(message);
    }
}
```